# Vb program loop with nested if statements

Tags: vb.net

I am running in circles trying to get this bit of code I wrote to simply add the bet amount, run the loop and add the bet amount, etc. If you lose then add it to the loss label, loop and finally keep track of the number of times you have bet.

Can you help me straighten it out?

```
Option Strict Off
Public Class RaceSeries
    ' declare variables
    Const intMAX_INDEX As Integer = 0
    Dim intBetValue As String
    Dim intBetValue2 As String
    Dim intRacerNum As String
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim intNum As Integer
    Dim rand As New Random
    Dim decGuess As Decimal
    Dim intBet As Integer
    Dim blnFlag1 As Boolean
    Dim blnFlag2 As Boolean

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnBetOnRace_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBetOnRace.Click
        'activate sound clip
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.FlyBy,
                         AudioPlayMode.Background)

        'verify Input() Is numeric and get bet amount
        intBetValue = InputBox("How much would you like to bet?")

        If IsNumeric(intBetValue) Then
            MsgBox("You are betting " & CInt(intBetValue).ToString("C"))
            blnFlag1 = True
        Else
            MsgBox("You provided an invalid value")
            blnFlag1 = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPick.Click
        ' verify input and get racer number
        intRacerNum = InputBox("Choose the racer you would like to bet on")

        If IsNumeric(intRacerNum) And intRacerNum < 7 And intRacerNum >= 1 Then
            MsgBox("You have picked racer # " & CInt(intRacerNum).ToString)
            blnFlag2 = True
        Else
            MsgBox("Choose a racer # 1-6")
            blnFlag2 = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        If blnFlag1 And blnFlag2 = True Then
            Do While Count <= intMAX_INDEX
                Count += 1

                'get a random integer and assign it to intnum
                intNum = rand.Next(6)

                If intNum <> intRacerNum Then
                    intBetValue = intBetValue * Count
                    lblLost.Text = intBetValue
                    MsgBox("Your Rider Lost The Race")
                    lblDailyBets.Text = Count
                    Exit Do
                ElseIf intNum = intRacerNum Then
                    intBetValue = intBetValue * Count
                    lblLost.Text = intBetValue
                    lblWinnings.Text = intBetValue
                    MsgBox("Congratulations, Your Rider Won The Race")
                End If
                lblDailyBets.Text = Count
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox("You must enter a bet and pick a racer")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That `Option Strict Off` alone makes me draw away from this quesiton.

Comment: Is IntMAX_INDEX supposed to be set to something other than zero?

Comment: I had it set to 3  at one time and a msgbox that said "this is a 3 series race"

Comment: but changed it in an effort to make it work

Comment: Please read [How To Debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

Your problems appear to be in the `btnStart_Click()` event.

the variable `intMAX_INDEX` doesn't appear to be set.  If this variable is set to anything more than zero, you are going to loop through multiple races every time you push the start button (This may be what you want, or not).

Also, you are multiplying win amount and loss amount by the Count.  Are you trying to make each race be a multiple larger than the previous race?  If not, you should not be multiplying your bet amount times Count.

Also, you are overwriting your win and loss label values after each race, which invalidates the previous race's winnings/losses.  If you are trying to keep a running total, you need to add in the existing amount of winnings/losses, like this:

```
lblWinnings.Text = CInt(lblWinnings.Text) + intBetValue
```

Lastly, I'm pretty sure that `rand.Next(6)` generates numbers in the range of 0 to 5, but will never return the number 6.  Since your user is choosing a number between 1 and 6 inclusive, you should be be setting `intNum = rand.Next(6)+1.`

Comment: thank you for the input and yes the random number used to have the +1 but ended up deleted at some point while rearanging

Comment: So I started over and wrote it out like the debug guide suggested and it works perfectly. Thanks.